# Support 5000 concurrent users of Apps Script Web App

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am in the process of architecting a small application for a G Suite customer. The app will be used by all employees at the customer and during peak times could see as many as 5,000 concurrent users.

They do not have App Maker and do not plan to enable App Maker anytime soon.

Will an Apps Script Web App be able to handle this many concurrent users?

Database:
I was originally thinking of using a Google Sheet as the database. There are no documented Apps Script limits around reading or writing data to a Google Sheet. So as long as I stay within the Google Sheets API quota limits I should be good.

With that said, I am also debating on using Cloud SQL as the database. App Maker forces you to use Cloud SQL so I assume it is a superior option to a Google Sheet. The only way I see to connect to Cloud SQL from Apps Script is via the JDBC service. However there is a hard limit of 50,000 connections per day. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas
Does anyone know if this limit is per app script or per user?
If per app script, then 5,000 users would only have 10 calls each per day. That would be unusable for my needs.

Side note, Google Cloud SQL has a maximum of 4,000 connections. I am banking on the fact that reads and writes will be extremely fast so max connections at a single point in time will be less than 4,000.

Comment: Note: `Simultaneous executions  30`

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but you might want to look at a firebase app.  You can log into the firebase console with the same user name and password as your Google account.  firebase does use the Google Cloud Platform, so I'm not sure what would be different, but you could check it out.  [https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#realtime_updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#realtime_updates)

Comment: I completely missed the simultaneous executions limit. I think that alone rules out Apps Script and means I need to look at Firebase or App Engine.

Answer (score 3):

As [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster) noted in the above comment you have a max of 30 simultaneous executions which limits you to a max of 30 concurrent users for a GAS Web App.

As an alternative you might be able to leverage [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) (basically just a Node.js/Express.js module). ̶M̶a̶x̶ ̶n̶u̶m̶b̶e̶r̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶c̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶r̶s̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶1̶0̶0̶0̶ ̶t̶h̶o̶u̶g̶h̶. It's not a free platform, but it supports CloudSQL and may be cheaper than getting a Google for Business account (US$11.00 per month per user) as required by App Maker.

Comment: I extrapolated from the section in the quota titled `Max concurrent invocations for a background function`. But that doesn't seem to apply to http requests so OP may be able to leverage Cloud Functions after all...