# Google Web App max simultaneous users capacity

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I'm launching a **Google Web App** (within the Google Workspace of a company), and I would like to know if it has a maximum capacity of simultaneous users and if so, I would like to know the max capacity number.

I searched on Google Workspace page, Google for Business page, developers.google.com, and Google Search but I couldn't find anything except [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557161/support-5000-concurrent-users-of-apps-script-web-app). The first response says the limit is 30 simultaneous users, but the other response says that with Google for Business you can increase it. Also, this article is two years old, so maybe things have changed.

If the maximum capacity is lower than 50 simultaneous users, I would like to know if someone has a way to increase it, or make a workaround. And if this isn't possible I would like to know if there is an alternative to overcome it.

From already thank you for your time and dedication!!

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search efforts as well more details of the deployment settings of your web app.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Is there any limit on number of concurrent hits or simultaneous executions on Google App Script Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17512194/1595451)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum simultaneous connections per user is 30. The same limit applies to Google Workspace users.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations

Because this is calculated on a per user basis, it depends how you've deployed it. If it's running as the user accessing the app, this limit shouldn't pose problems. If it's running as you (the person deploying the app), you'll start to see errors when more than 30 people are concurrently accessing it.